# HP: Set media buttons on the Fx buttons as secundary action

Tags: hp, media-buttons

I've an HP laptop with media keys. The primairy action F2 button is to dim screen, F7 is pauze current song, F8 next song etc, F11 mute.

When I want to use the real function of an Fx button I have to press the Fn button (between ctrl and super button) at the same time. So to go fullscreen I've to press Fn + F11 at the same time.

How can I revert this?
So fo that F11 I go fullscreen and Fn + F11 mutes my sound?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the setting in the BIOS:

When you computer is booting, press <kbd>F10</kbd> to access BIOS settings.

Navigate to:

> System Configuration

and set:

> Action Keys Mode

to:

> Disabled

Save and exit.

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c02035108